# How to count instances of words in multiple lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm new to python and I'm learning it slowly. I'm trying to code a simple word counter that tracks instances of words across multiple lines. I'm attempting to place the line into a list and then track each list point in a dictionary, whilst removing each word from the list as the dictionary is updated. So far I have:

```
dic = {}
count = ''
liste = line.split()
listes = liste[0]
num = 0
while line:
  while not liste:
    listes = liste[0]
    if listes in dic:
      count = str(dic[listes])
      count = count.rstrip("]")
      count = count.lstrip("[")
      count = int(count) + 1
      liste.pop(0)
    else:
      skadoing = 1
  dic [listes] = [skadoing]
  line = input("Enter line: ")
for word in sorted(dic):
  print(word, dic[word])
```

When run, it currently outputs the following:

```
Enter line: which witch
Enter line: is which
Enter line: 
which ['']
```

I need it to output this:

```
Enter line: which witch
Enter line: is which
Enter line: 
is 1
which 2
witch 1
```

`liste` is the list of words from the inputted line and `listes` is the word that I'm trying to update in the dictionary.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is `which=2` and `witch=1` while the input is just `is which`?

Comment: That's not a good idea. I advise  you to use python built-in [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) (`from collections import Counter`) which counts the occurences of words from a list so you could just split it and the work is done!

Comment: formatting issue Code Pope. Amin Guermazi, how do I use the counter() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking to achieve:

```
dic = {}
line = input("Enter line: ")
while line:
    for word in line.split(" "):
        if word not in dic:
            dic[word] = 1
        else:
            dic[word] +=1
    line = input("Enter line: ")
for word in sorted(dic):
    print(word, dic[word])
```

Output:

```
Enter line: hello world
Enter line: world
Enter line: 
hello 1
world 2
```

Comment: Seems to work fine but not with whitespace. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to implement this by yourself and count the words, then it would be great to use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
sentence = '''this is a test for which is witch and which
because of which'''
words = sentence.split()
d = defaultdict(int)
for word in words:
  d[word] = d[word]+ 1
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'a': 1, 'test': 1, 'for': 1, 'which': 3, 'witch': 1, 'and': 1, 'because': 1, 'of': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the collections package to do the job:-

```
from collections import Counter
line = input("Enter line: ")
words = line.split(" ")
word_count = dict(Counter(words))
print(word_count)
```

```
Enter line: hi how are you are you fine

{'hi': 1, 'how': 1, 'are': 2, 'you': 2, 'fine': 1}
```

Hope this helps!!